# Why is my .htaccess rewrite rule redirecting to the wrong place

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

This is the my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc-something-old\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myglobalsite.com/$1 [R,L]

## DIRECTORY
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.myglobalsite.com/

redirectMatch 301 ^/products$ https://www.myglobalsite.com/en/product/drinking-cups
redirectMatch 301 ^/products/vending.php$ https://www.myglobalsite.com/en/product/drinking-cups
redirectMatch 301 ^/products/drinking.php$ https://www.myglobalsite.com/en/product/drinking-cups
```

The issue is when it redirects, it redirects as follows:

from:
https://www.abc-something-old.com/products/vending.php

to:
https://www.myglobalsite.com/products/vending.php

should redirect to:
https://www.myglobalsite.com/en/product/drinking-cups

is the problem in my rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives in configuration files (a ".htaccess" fils is a "distributed configuration file") are processed from top to bottom.

The first redirection rule redirects *all* requests to the same resource path on the new domain. That means that your `RedirectMatch` directives further down never come into play.

You have to change the order of directives such that specialized, so more precise rules go to the top to get applied *first* . Also don't forget to correctly type the names of directives, so `RedirectMatch` instead of `redirectMatch`. More general rules, so typically catch-all rules go to the bottom to get applied as a last option if no specialized rule got applied before.

```
## DIRECTORY
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.myglobalsite.com/

RedirectMatch 301 ^/products$ https://www.myglobalsite.com/en/product/drinking-cups
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/vending.php$ https://www.myglobalsite.com/en/product/drinking-cups
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/drinking.php$ https://www.myglobalsite.com/en/product/drinking-cups

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc-something-old\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.myglobalsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

So far you are using a mixture of directives from the alias module and the rewrite module. You could unify that, though both approaches will work:

```
## DIRECTORY
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.myglobalsite.com/
    
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc-something-old\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?products/?$ https://www.myglobalsite.com/en/product/drinking-cups [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc-something-old\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?products/vending\.php$ https://www.myglobalsite.com/en/product/drinking-cups [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc-something-old\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?products/drinking\.php$ https://www.myglobalsite.com/en/product/drinking-cups [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc-something-old\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.myglobalsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

And by the way: you only need the `RewriteCond` if *both* domains are served by the same http server and evaluate the same configuration file to process a request. Otherwise, if those are separate servers or separate virtual hosts with separate `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folders (which I would *strongly* recommend), you can simplify that:

```
## DIRECTORY
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes

DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.myglobalsite.com/
    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?products/?$ https://www.myglobalsite.com/en/product/drinking-cups [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/?products/vending\.php$ https://www.myglobalsite.com/en/product/drinking-cups [R,L]
RewriteRule ^/?products/drinking\.php$ https://www.myglobalsite.com/en/product/drinking-cups [R,L]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.myglobalsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```